# How should I call model class which is written in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I have model class which is written in MVC.I am using Ef database first approach. In model class I have some queries which deals with database. I have following questions :

1) Is it right way to use database related queries in Model and call that in controller or view?

2)If yes where I should call this model? In Controller or in view ??

3)How I should call this model? Say for example I have class called class1.cs in model.How I should call this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model contains classes that define the different objects troughout your project. This includes properties with their basic information and methods to perform actions on this object.

1)
Do you really need queries? Why not use the Entity Framework to do it for you? Create the mapping for your domain classes (either trough annotations or fluent api) and use the `DbContext` to retrieve and save the data stored in your database

2) 
Ideally people create repositories that are injected into your controllers (Dependency Injection). These repositories can for example contain something like `GetPersonById(int id)`. Inside this method there would be two things:

1. Perform an action on the domain object
2. Save it to the `DbContext`

For example:

```
public void Subscribe(int userID, Show show) {
   var user = GetUserByID(userID);
   if (!user.IsSubscribedTo(show.ShowID)) {
       user.Subscribe(show);
       _dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Controller -> Method call in repository -> Perform action on corresponding domain object -> Save changes to the database

If you need something that doesn't require an object mutation, it's even more simple:

```
public User GetUserByID(int id) {
     return _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
}
```

3)
Trough repositories (see above). Your `DbContext` will have a bunch of `DbSets` that contain objects that correspond with every data entry in your database. Trough repositories you can work with these objects and manipulate them. When you call the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method, it will look at what has changed in these lists and commit the changes to your database.

Repository example:

```
class User {
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}

class DatabaseContext : DbContext {
 public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserRepository {
 User GetUserByID (int id);
 bool UsernameExists (string name);
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository {
 private DatabaseContext _db;

 public UserRepository(DatabaseContext db){
  _db = db;
 }

 public User GetUserByID(int id) {
  return _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
 }

 public User GetUserByUsername(string username) {
  return _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == username);
 }
}

public class UserController : Controller {
 private IUserRepository _userRepository;

 public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository) {
  _userRepository = userRepository;
 }

 public ActionResult Details(int id){
  return View(_userRepository.GetUserByID(id);
 }
}

// Ninject settings (install this extension, you want it):
private void AddBindings(){
 kernel.Bind<DatabaseContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
 kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InRequestScope();
}
```

Comment: Hi I am using Entity framework to access database contents. I dont know anything about repository. I heard only about model, view and controller. And what i know is I can use EF Dbcontext to fetch data from database in controller and pass that to view for display. Do i really need to use repository? Is it difficult topic to learn? Sorry it may be dumb question, please dont mind..

Comment: @Dev: I have added an example of using a repository. A repository is nothing more than a class that you use to separate the actual domain classes from the persistence layer. Take a look at it and let me know if something's unclear.

Comment: I will tell what I understood.please correct me if i am wrong.1) Basically we create repository inside models with separate class name,example:myrepo- just to maintain better understanding and structure of code. 2)can i write all operations in one repository only.What I mean is if i have to to do one operation with table1 and another operation with table1 and table2,another with table3, can i write EF in one repo only or do i need to create separate repo for every operations?

Comment: You should create a repository for every type of data you want to use in your tables. If you want to use users then you create a `UserRepository`. If you want to manage articles, create an `ArticleRepository`. You could throw them all together in one repository, but that would be extremely ugly and hard to maintain. Give each type of data its own repository.

Comment: so i will create folder called DAL inside Model and will place all repositories inside DAL folder.Is that sounds good for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of Unit Of Work pattern which you inject in your controller constructor using an inversion of control container (IOC), for instance autofac.

Your unit of work class could hold a reference to repositories, where you would query/insert your data.

Roughly;

```
public class BackendController : Controller
{
    private UnitOfWork _worker;

    public BackendController(UnitOfWork worker)
    {
        this._worker = worker;
    }

    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        var items = _worker.MyRepository.GetAll();
        return View(items);
    }
}


public class UnitOfWork
{
    private ContentRepository _contentRepository;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
    }


    public ContentRepository MyRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_contentRepository != null)
                return _contentRepository;
            else
                return _contentRepository = new ContentRepository();
        }
    }
}

public class ContentRepository
{
    // holds an object context and methods to retrieve and put data (EF or similar)


}
```

You would have to register your instance with the IOC container in global.asax, application_start for example, something like this (Using autofac as IOC):

```
UnitOfWork worker = new UnitOfWork();
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterInstance(worker).SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();
```

...

Answer (score 0):

1) Is it right way to use database related queries in Model and call that in controller or view?

I would recommend not directly accessing the database in your model classes, as you have to remember that MVC is strictly a presentation layer pattern. If you do put your database access logic in your model classes, then you will not be able to have any other client use this functionality, such as a web service. Instead have logic that translates your business objects, defined outside of your ASP.NET MVC project, into your ASP.NET MVC model classes.

This is where the power of n-tier architecture shines, if you create a business and data-access layer, then I could write an ASP.NET MVC front-end, WebForms front-end, WPF front-end, WinForms front-end and all of them could access data using the same service. By putting the logic into the ASP.NET MVC model classes, then you are effectively forcing any other client to duplicate that logic again in their classes.